# Problems with RGeo intersection functions

Tags: ruby, geometry, geospatial, rgeo

I'm getting strange/incorrect results from RGeo polygon intersection functions (Ruby 2.3.0, RGeo 0.5.3)

### EXAMPLE 1:

I have two polygons which I believe share a boundary but do not share any internal space (i.e. they [touch](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Touches.html) but do not [overlap](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Overlaps.html)):

```
wkt_1 = "POLYGON ((-8226874.27782158 4962626.76394919, -8223358.174520462 4961756.817075645, -8223358.174520462 4960289.557693501, -8224471.369428394 4960289.557693501, -8226874.27782158 4962253.674727506, -8226874.27782158 4962626.76394919))"
wkt_2 = "POLYGON ((-8224757.546680832 4960523.476563589, -8225269.1002275925 4959296.105368667, -8226993.791361805 4959219.668340384, -8226420.900079966 4961883.087589158, -8224757.546680832 4960523.476563589))"
poly_1 = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 3857).parse_wkt(wkt_1)
poly_2 = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 3857).parse_wkt(wkt_2)
```

When we check the intersection between them, it returns a line, as expected for geometries sharing only a boundary:

```
poly_1.intersection poly_2
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPILineStringImpl:0x3fc0249af168 "LINESTRING (-8224757.546680832 4960523.476563589, -8225598.074380083 4961210.51680879)">
```

However, when running the following checks, we get the opposite of what's expected:

```
poly_1.overlaps? poly_2
=> true
poly_1.touches? poly_2
=> false
```

### EXAMPLE 2:

We take two legitimately overlapping polygons:

```
wkt_3 = "POLYGON ((-8243237.0 4970203.0, -8243237.0 4968735.0, -8242123.0 4968735.0, -8242123.0 4970203.0, -8243237.0 4970203.0))"
wkt_4 = "POLYGON ((-8244765.0 4966076.0, -8244765.0 4964608.0, -8243652.0 4964608.0, -8243652.0 4966076.0, -8242680.0 4969362.0, -8244765.0 4966076.0))"
poly_3 = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 3857).parse_wkt(wkt_3)
poly_4 = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 3857).parse_wkt(wkt_4)
```

[image]

And calculate the differences in both directions:

```
diff_a = poly_3.difference poly_4
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPolygonImpl:0x3fe3fca26028 "POLYGON ((-8243077.837796713 4968735.0, -8243237.0 4968735.0, -8243237.0 4970203.0, -8242123.0 4970203.0, -8242123.0 4968735.0, -8242865.466828971 4968735.0, -8242680.0 4969362.0, -8243077.837796713 4968735.0))">
diff_b = poly_4.difference poly_3
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPolygonImpl:0x3fe3fd1dda28 "POLYGON ((-8242865.466828971 4968735.0, -8243652.0 4966076.0, -8243652.0 4964608.0, -8244765.0 4964608.0, -8244765.0 4966076.0, -8243077.837796713 4968735.0, -8242865.466828971 4968735.0))">
```

Now we check the remainder polygons against their subtractors:

```
diff_b.touches? poly_3
=> true
diff_b.overlaps? poly_3
=> false
```

This is good.

```
diff_a.touches? poly_4
=> false
diff_a.overlaps? poly_4
=> true
```

This is IMPOSSIBLE- There's no way the remainder of a polygon subtracted from another should be able to overlap that polygon!

And why is it only happening in one direction?

### EXAMPLE 3:

The weirdness continues. Let's now get the intersection of poly_3 and poly_4

```
intersection_a = poly_3.intersection poly_4
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPolygonImpl:0x3fd1084ece88 "POLYGON ((-8242865.724520766 4968734.582337743, -8243078.32501591 4968734.582337743, -8242680.062418439 4969362.301390027, -8242865.724520766 4968734.582337743))">
```

Now since this is what should have been subtracted from poly_3 to give us diff_a, diff_a should therefore intersect with intersection_a in exactly the same way as that it intersects with poly_4 (the subtractor).

Except it doesn't:

```
diff_a.touches? poly_4
=> false
diff_a.touches? intersection_a
=> true
diff_a.intersection poly_4
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPILineStringImpl:0x3fe3f98fb854 "LINESTRING (-8242680.0 4969362.0, -8243077.837796713 4968735.0)">
diff_a.intersection intersection_a
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIMultiLineStringImpl:0x3fe3fca157b4 "MULTILINESTRING ((-8242865.466828971 4968735.0, -8242680.0 4969362.0), (-8242680.0 4969362.0, -8243077.837796713 4968735.0))">
```

Worse, neither of those two intersection results make sense. It should be a single, 2-segmented line, which neither of those are.

Comment: Interesting, but I have no idea where this could come from. cloning https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo and using `git grep -A5 "overlaps?"` doesn't show much information. Did you try it with another srid?

Comment: @EricDuminil - Just tried it with srid 4326 - same result. Moreover, I would think that if the intersection is a line, then what would mean a touching, not overlapping intersection, no matter what the coordinate space?

Comment: True. You might have to calculate the intersection and checks manually if the result is empty, a (multi-)point, a (multi-)linestring or a (multi-)polygon.

Comment: @EricDuminil Kind of defeats the purpose of using a library

Comment: Sure, but if the lib fails...

Comment: Just out of wonder, what version of Ruby and RGeo are you using?

Comment: Because using Ruby 2.4.0 and RGeo 0.5.3, `RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 3857)` itself returns `nil`, so it seems like there might be some lib errors.

Comment: @EliSadoff Ruby 2.3.0, RGeo 0.5.3. If you're not able to load the factory it may be that you don't have the underlying GEOS lib installed. You can check by doing `RGeo::Geos.supported?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer

Unfortunately, it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900068/6419007) that you cannot expect reliable and correct output from `touches?` and `overlaps?` when using Float coordinates.

It doesn't depend on RGeo or GEOS versions (or for that matter, [JTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite), the project on which GEOS is based).

If you need information about the position of two polygons, you could use [`Geometry#distance`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/dazuma/rgeo/RGeo/Feature/Geometry:distance) and check that it is smaller than a given epsilon.

[`Geometry#intersection`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/dazuma/rgeo/RGeo/Feature/Geometry#intersection-instance_method) is a bit more reliable than `touches?` and `overlaps?`, but it isn't guaranteed to work with every example either.

---

## Is it a precision problem?

#### Theory

`touches?` is by definition very sensitive : polygons have to share a point or a line on their border, but shouldn't have any common interior points.

- If they're too far away from each other, they don't have any point in common, and `touches?` is false.
- If they're too close, their intersection is a polygon, and `touches?` is false.

#### Sensitivity analysis

How sensitive is it exactly?

Let's consider two polygons, one just above the other :

[image]

```
POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 0 1))
```

We could move the lower border of the upper polygon by an epsilon, and see which influence it has :

```
require 'rgeo'

epsilon = 1E-15

deltas = [-epsilon, 0, epsilon]

deltas.each do |delta|
  puts "--------------------------------"
  puts "Delta : #{delta}\n\n"
  simple1 = 'POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'
  simple2 = "POLYGON((0 #{1+delta}, 0 2, 1 2, 1 #{1+delta}, 0 #{1+delta}))"

  puts "Polygon #1 : #{simple1}\n"
  puts "Polygon #2 : #{simple2}\n\n"

  poly_1 = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 4326).parse_wkt(simple1)
  poly_2 = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 4326).parse_wkt(simple2)

  puts "Intersection : #{poly_1.intersection poly_2}"
  puts

  puts "Distance between polygons :"
  puts format('%.30f°', poly_1.distance(poly_2))
  puts

  puts "Overlaps? : #{poly_1.overlaps? poly_2}"
  puts "Touches? : #{poly_1.touches? poly_2}"
end
```

It outputs :

```
--------------------------------
Delta : -1.0e-15

Polygon #1 : POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
Polygon #2 : POLYGON((0 0.999999999999999, 0 2, 1 2, 1 0.999999999999999, 0 0.999999999999999))

Intersection : POLYGON ((0.0 0.999999999999999, 0.0 1.0, 1.0 1.0, 1.0 0.999999999999999, 0.0 0.999999999999999))

Distance between polygons :
0.000000000000000000000000000000°

Overlaps? : true
Touches? : false
--------------------------------
Delta : 0

Polygon #1 : POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
Polygon #2 : POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 0 1))

Intersection : LINESTRING (0.0 1.0, 1.0 1.0)

Distance between polygons :
0.000000000000000000000000000000°

Overlaps? : false
Touches? : true
--------------------------------
Delta : 1.0e-15

Polygon #1 : POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
Polygon #2 : POLYGON((0 1.000000000000001, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1.000000000000001, 0 1.000000000000001))

Intersection : GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY

Distance between polygons :
0.000000000000001110223024625157°

Overlaps? : false
Touches? : false
```

Those are well behaved polygons, with

- sides parallel to the axes
- same size
- a shared side over the whole length

A difference of `1E-15` of a degree (about [1 Ångström](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m)) is enough to completely change the results, and both `overlaps?` and `touches?` switch between `true` and `false`.

The intersection is either empty, a line or a polygon, but at least the results seem consistent between `intersection`, `overlaps?` and `touches?`.

In your case, having more complex polygons with tilted sides makes the problem harder. When calculating intersection of two segments, it's hard to maintain 1-Ångström accuracy!

## Is it a problem with RGeo?

[RGeo](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo) uses [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/), which is a C++ port of [JTS (Java Topology Suite)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/).

In order to check that the problem isn't specific to RGeo or GEOS, I calculated 
Example 1 with JTS 1.14 :

```
WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
String wkt1 = "POLYGON ((-8226874.27782158 4962626.76394919, -8223358.174520462 4961756.817075645, -8223358.174520462 4960289.557693501, -8224471.369428394 4960289.557693501, -8226874.27782158 4962253.674727506, -8226874.27782158 4962626.76394919))";
String wkt2 = "POLYGON ((-8224757.546680832 4960523.476563589, -8225269.1002275925 4959296.105368667, -8226993.791361805 4959219.668340384, -8226420.900079966 4961883.087589158, -8224757.546680832 4960523.476563589))";
Polygon poly1 = (Polygon) wktReader.read(wkt1);
Polygon poly2 = (Polygon) wktReader.read(wkt2);
System.out.println("Intersection : " + poly1.intersection(poly2));
System.out.println("Overlaps?    : " + poly1.overlaps(poly2));
System.out.println("Intersects?  : " + poly1.intersects(poly2));
System.out.println("Touches?     : " + poly1.touches(poly2));
showMatrixWith(poly1, poly2);
```

It outputs :

```
Intersection : LINESTRING (-8224757.546680832 4960523.476563589, -8225598.074380083 4961210.51680879)
Overlaps?    : true
Intersects?  : true
Touches?     : false

212
101
212
```

The intersection is the exact same as in your example, `intersects?` and `touches?`
 output the same wrong results as RGeo.

## Why are results inconsistent?

Why do `intersection` and `touches?` return inconsistend results?

#### DE-9IM

`touches?`, `intersects?`, `overlaps?` and other predicates are derived from [the Dimensionally Extended nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM). It's a matrix describing the dimensions of intersection between interiors, boundaries and exteriors of geometries.

This matrix is calculated on line 72 of `src/operation/relate/RelateComputer.cpp` in GEOS :

```
IntersectionMatrix* RelateComputer::computeIM()
```

The algorithm seems to [require exact noding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900068/6419007), which isn't the case in any of your examples.

All the tests that I could find for JTS used integers coordinates, even a test called "complex polygons touching" :

```
  # line 477 in jts-1.14/testxml/general/TestFunctionAA.xml
  <desc>mAmA - complex polygons touching</desc>
  <a>
    MULTIPOLYGON(
      (
        (100 200, 100 180, 120 180, 120 200, 100 200)),
      (
        (60 240, 60 140, 220 140, 220 160, 160 160, 160 180, 200 180, 200 200, 160 200,
        160 220, 220 220, 220 240, 60 240),
        (80 220, 80 160, 140 160, 140 220, 80 220)),
      (
        (280 220, 240 180, 260 160, 300 200, 280 220)))
  </a>
  <b>
    MULTIPOLYGON(
      (
        (80 220, 80 160, 140 160, 140 220, 80 220),
        (100 200, 100 180, 120 180, 120 200, 100 200)),
      (
        (220 240, 220 220, 160 220, 160 200, 220 200, 220 180, 160 180, 160 160, 220 160,
        220 140, 320 140, 320 240, 220 240),
        (240 220, 240 160, 300 160, 300 220, 240 220)))
  </b>
```

There's not a single test case where predicates are calculated for floating-point coordinates.

Note that even though `wkt_3` and `wkt_4` have rounded coordinates in your example, calculating their differences create polygons with inexact coordinates : `x1` of `diff_a` is `-8243077.837796713`.

#### Geometry#intersection

`Geometry#intersection` is calculated on line 670 of `src/operation/overlay/OverlayOp.cpp` in GEOS :

```
void OverlayOp::computeOverlay(OverlayOp::OpCode opCode)
```

Comments in the code seems to indicate that exact noding isn't required, and there are multiple if statements to check if the results appear correct.

This method seems to be more robust than `RelateComputer::computeIM`.

## Using GeometryPrecisionReducer?

With `GeometryPrecisionReducer` and a `PrecisionModel`, it becomes possible to specify a grid of allowable points for all Geometries.

`GeometryPrecisionReducer` is implemented in GEOS, but isn't available in RGeo.
Tests in JTS with your first example have shown that it doesn't solve your problem anyway : inexact coordinates are snapped to the closest point on the grid. Every point is moved a bit to the north/south/east or west, which changes the slopes of every side.

It also changes the boundaries and their intersections. Depending on the `PrecisionModel`, the intersection for your first example could be empty, a line or a polygon.

Comment: My pleasure. I love Ruby, GIS and big bounties :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you have provided some floating point numbers for two polygons. What makes you think that they touch and do not overlap? How can you tell? In a generic case, you cannot say in absolute terms (without using tolerances) if two line segments overlap exactly or not. You can provide lines that have rounded coordinates, in which case an argument can be made for the same.

Use of floating-point numbers is a form of discretization of the real number space. This causes inconsistent results when using different algorithms or methods to compute the same result. For example, consider an intersection of three lines in 2D space such that they are supposed to intersect at the same point. Now compute the intersection point, independently, three times using a different pair of lines each time. You are likely to get similar but unequal answers each time.

I haven't used RGeo, but is there a way to adjust tolerances when computing intersection geometries? Try reducing the tolerance value (make that threshold smaller). This will allow the function to compute the geometry without merging points that are too close to each other.

Comment: I thought you were on to something, so I redid examples 2-3 with rounded values (see edits above), but unfortunately I'm getting the same results.